# Canon lens hood will not lock (brand new)

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, lens-hood

I have a `Canon 7D Mark II` with the **standard kit lens (EF-S 18-135 mm)**. I bought the **EW-73D** hood for it and it slots in to the bayonet mount but will not turn and lock no matter what I do. I don't want to force it and break the latch.

**Neither the lens mount nor the hood look to be damaged**, but it just won't turn. Has anybody else experienced this? All of my old lenses (EF series) had the click on hoods, not bayonet mounts, so I'm not super familiar with the hiccups they might have. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

The lens hood you bought is for the EF 18-135mm f/3.5-5.6 IS USM, but the standard kit lens supplied with a Canon EOS 7D Mark II should be an EF 18-135mm f/3.5-6.3 IS STM. Though the names are very similar, they are two different lens designs which share the same focal length and aperture ranges. If I am not mistaken you will need the EW-73B, check also [Canon.](https://store.canon.co.uk/canon-ew-73b-lens-hood/9823A001/)

Comment: You are correct. The older 18-135 STM uses the EW-73B while the newer 18-135 USM uses the EW-73D.